# Android IP Traffic Routing - Cellular IP on WiFi?

Tags: android, linux, routes, ip, wifi

While capturing some traffic with Wireshark from an Android phone, I noticed a strange side-effect. Shortly after a new network connection to WiFi, there seem to be a few packets that "leak" on the WiFi interface that retain the Cellular IP source address. This does not normally last for long, and it seems those connections are quickly stopped and restarted with the new WiFi IP address.

What causes this effect? Does a routing switch redirect the packets to the new interface, but allows them to keep the old address? What kind of errors would an application see in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IP packets are created at one layer while routing of them is done at a lower layer.  When the cellular "interface" closes and the routing table updates, all packets not destined for the local subnet get sent to the "default gateway".  Since that gateway is reachable through the WiFi interface, that's where the packets get sent.  Routing occurs based only on the destination address, not the source address.

Those packets will still reach their destination if there is no firewall or router that drops them (which is actually likely in this day of stateful routers and protected networks) but the reply packets would get directed to the cellular provider which no longer has a connection to the phone and so get dropped or result in an ICMP "host unreachable" message back to the server.

The application on the phone won't see any error from this, only an absence of a response.  However, other behaviors on the system can be noticed by the app; for example, the OS *could* automatically generate reset (RST) packets for all connections using the IP address of a closed interface.

A TCP connection cannot change network addresses or ports, destination *or* source of either, while open.  It must be closed (or reset) and a new connection started.